# how to make execv reattach to a running process

Tags: c

I created a C program that is using the execv function to start a daemon process of another program and read its stdout.

I have achieved that by using the fork and setsid functions.

Everything works great. But if the program exit i want to be able to
reattach to a running process again and read the stdout.

I can store the pid of the process if that can be used.

Can someone please tell me if it even possible ? and how that can be done in C please.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reattach to running process". What do you want to achieve with this "reattach"?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I want to reattach to read the stdout of the process

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61652450/edit) your question by providing some [MRE]. Your question is operating system specific. If on Linux, read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch how would i if i don't know what works? i'm seeking knowledge about the subject.

Comment: You should explain much better your question. I am not even capable to understand it

Comment: I have updated my explanation . Hope it's little more clear what i'm asking

Comment: Why can't you provide some [mre] or at least list all the [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) used by your program (which is Linux or POSIX specific BTW). Read also -for Linux- [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html). Study the source code of similar [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) programs